# C programming reading multiple integers in same line

Tags: c, file, scanf, fopen, dev-c++

I am trying to read a .txt file with integers in it and store it in a structure array. I can read the first file which has an additional char data as follows with this code:

```
fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
while(fscanf(fp, "%s %d %d %d %d", a[i].letter , &a[i].hor, &a[i].width , &a[i].ver, &a[i].height)==5 && i<LineCount){
    
    if(ferror(fp)  ||  feof(fp)) break;
    i++;
}
```

- A 10 213 20 20
- B 100 10 150 15
- ....

However, after that when I try to read the other file which has the following format, with this code:

```
file1 = fopen("beg.txt", "r");
    printf("HELLOOOO");
    while(fscanf(file1, "%d %d %d %d", &b[i].id, &b[i].hor, &b[i].ver, &b[i].time)==4 && i<LineCount){
    printf("HEYY");

        if(ferror(file1)  ||  feof(file1)) break;
    
        i++;
    }
```

Format :

- 1 10 100 100
- 2 100 10 100
- 3 172 172 18
- ....

fopen does not return NULL so it opens, I can see the "HELLOOOO" but it never makes it to the "HEYY" and program exits, not immediately but in a short time. I double checked everything, file and the structure is in the right format, I am doing the exact same operation with the first one but it does not work.

If you have any idea what I am doing wrong or what could be the possible issues I would appreciate your comments.

Comment: What's the value of `i` before reading the second file? To be honest, from what I read you haven't tried everything yet. For example, does your `fscanf()` fail or not? Please spend a bit more time, this is a very simple program you should be able to debug with either a few print statements or in a debugger.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. `i` is 0. I have actually tried printing in every step and I was unable to detect the source of the problem. I have just figured out something. I can read the second file if I don't read the first one. Also, if I declare one more variable in main and assign it a value before the reading. I cannot even read one file. So if I declare more variables than the current ones I cannot read a file or If a read a file I cannot read another one. I am not that experienced with C so I don't have knowledge about this stuff. Is this a memory related problem or a hardware issue?

Comment: Maybe `i>=LineCount` ?

Comment: Please create the smallest complete program that still has this issue and post that, together with the first few lines of your files. At the moment you only show a few pieces so it's guesswork what could be wrong. Why do you think about a hardware or memory issue for a program like this; do you run this on a buggy microcontroller board with very limited memory?

Comment: Okay, I'll repost the question in that way. I think that because I read the file in a function and it works, I declare any variable in main() before that function and it stops working. Any variable such as `int u = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Here I have created another program from scratch and done all the operations in main. Still having the same problem. First file is read, stored in structure and printed with no issues. However, for the second file even fopen() does not work this time, it also doesn't return any value, null or -1. It just waits and exits the program.

Structures:

```
struct data{
        char name[2];
        int a,b,c,d;
    };

struct fix{
    int x,y,z,u;
};
```

Reading First File:

```
    char c;
    
    
    int lineCount = 1;
fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
 for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp)){ //Get the number of lines
        if (c == '\n'){ 
            lineCount = LineCount + 1; 
            }
             }      
    fclose(fp);     
    
int i=0;
struct data* a;
a = (struct data*)malloc(sizeof(a)*lineCount);  //Allocate memory for a      

fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
if(fp==NULL) printf("Null\n");
while(fscanf(fp, "%s %d %d %d %d", a[i].name , &a[i].a, &a[i].b , &a[i].c, &a[i].d)==5 && i<lineCount){
    
    if(ferror(fp)  ||  feof(fp)) break;
    i++;

fclose(fp);
for(i=0;i<lineCount;i++){

printf("%s, ", a[i].name);
printf("%d, ", a[i].a);
printf("%d, ", a[i].b);
printf("%d, ", a[i].c);
printf("%d\n", a[i].d);
}
```

Reading the second file:

```
lineCount = 1;

//files=fopen("beg.txt","r");
if(files=fopen("beg.txt","r")==NULL) printf("Hey"); //STUCK HERE!

if(files==NULL) printf("NULL2");
 for (c = getc(files); c != EOF; c = getc(files)){ //Get the number of lines
        if (c == '\n'){     //Get t
            lineCount = lineCount + 1; 
            }
             }
        
struct fix* b = (struct fix*)malloc(sizeof(b)*lineCount);   //Allocate memory for b     

files = fopen("beg.txt", "r"); 
while(fscanf(files, "%d %d %d %d", &b[i].x, &b[i].y , &b[i].z, &b[i].u)==4 && i<lineCount){
    
    if(ferror(fp)  ||  feof(fp)) break;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Given `char c;`, `c != EOF` won't work because `EOF` is an `int`, not a `char`.  `c != EOF` will either fail to detect end-of-file, or it will prematurely detect end-of-file when a `char` value read from the file is promoted to `int` and matches the actual bits of the `EOF` integer value.  `getc()` returns `int` and not `char` for that reason.

Comment: I see. But it worked correctly for the first file and It is a commonly used practice am I wrong? Do you think this may cause the problem I am having? How else could I count the number of lines?